# Singleton with private destructor using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, destructor, unique-ptr

I've created all singletons in my program with that document in mind:
http://erdani.com/publications/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf
(in case anyone wondered why singleton, all of them are factories and some of them store some global settings concerning how they should create instances).

Each of them looks somehow like this:

declaration:

```
class SingletonAndFactory {
    static SingletonAndFactory* volatile instance;

public:
    static SingletonAndFactory& getInstance();

private:
    SingletonAndFactory();

    SingletonAndFactory(
        const SingletonAndFactory& ingletonFactory
    );

    ~SingletonAndFactory();
};
```

definition:

```
boost::mutex singletonAndFactoryMutex;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// class SingletonAndFactory {

SingletonAndFactory* volatile singletonAndFactory::instance = 0;

// public:

SingletonAndFactory& SingletonAndFactory::getInstance() {
    // Singleton implemented according to:
    // "C++ and the Perils of Double-Checked Locking".
    if (!instance) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(SingletonAndFactoryMutex);
        if (!instance) {
            SingletonAndFactory* volatile tmp = (SingletonAndFactory*) malloc(sizeof(SingletonAndFactory));
            new (tmp) SingletonAndFactory; // placement new
            instance = tmp;
        }
    }
    return *instance;
}

// private:

SingletonAndFactory::SingletonAndFactory() {}

// };
```

Putting aside question *what design of singleton is the best* (since it would start a pointless flame war) my question is: would it benefit me to replace normal pointer with std::unique_ptr? In particular, would it call singleton's destructor on program exit? If so how would I achieve it? When I tried to add something like `friend class std::unique_ptr<SingletonAndFactory>;` it didn't worked out since compiler keep on complaining that the destructor is private.

I know it doesn't matter in my current project since none of factories have something that would require cleaning of any sort, but for future reference I would like to know how to implement such behavior.

Comment: `Thing& getThing() {
    static Thing thing;
    return thing;
}` Forget the locks, forget the singletons.

Comment: And... *seriously*? `malloc` + placement new? Oh, come on...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: If you're going to use singletons, you might as well make them as wrong as possible. There are those who advocate [making wrong code look wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

Comment: I also wonder if the pointer is used for memory-mapped I/O, because it is tagged `volatile`. C++11 assigns no thread-related semantics to `volatile`.

Comment: It looks like the `volatile` was copied from an example in the linked document describing how `volatile` was **not** sufficient for thread safety. You need C++11 to provide the necessary atomicity guarantees; and once you've got C++11, you might as well use a local static.

Comment: [Singletons: Solving problems you didn’t know you never had since 1995](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/)

Comment: I came up with some solution when I still didn't used -std=c++11 flag,  and I knew about C++ much less that I do now (though it's still isn't much). If C++11 finally gives some atomicity I might replace whole malloc thing with simple constructor but that's just a matter of implementation of one function. That's why I didn't asked about way to implements singleton - as long as API doesn't change and tests passes I can switch implementation behind them to something better any time I want. Though thanks for information about that particular C++11 feature. It will be helpful.

Comment: @maddening: The malloc madness doesn't do anything to help thread safety here. Both `instance = new Thing;` and your nonsense involve a single assignment to `instance`, and are therefore as safe (or, in this case, unsafe) as each other.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well, NOW I am aware of that malloc and placement new are pointless but I wasn't at the moment when I was writing that particular piece of code. Only recently I started too understand C++ a little better I started to use flags `-std=C++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and e.g. changed BOOST_FOREACH to C++11 for. getInstance body was written when I was literally starting my adventure with C++ having mainly Java SE background. It took several weeks of coding and reading to understand some things. So recently I'm rewriting some parts of my code to be better. I'll deal with malloc as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the `unique_ptr` itself that does the deletion, it's the deleter. So if you wanted to go with the `friend` approach, you'd have to do this:

```
friend std::unique_ptr<SingletonFactory>::deleter_type;
```

However, I don't think it's guaranteed that the default deleter will not delegate the actual `delete` to another function, which would break this.

Instead, you might want to supply your own deleter, perhaps like this:

```
class SingletonFactory {
    static std::unique_ptr<SingletonFactory, void (*)(SingletonFactory*)> volatile instance;

public:
    static SingletonFactory& getInstance();

private:
    SingletonFactory();

    SingletonFactory(
        const SingletonFactory& ingletonFactory
    );

    ~SingletonFactory();

    void deleter(SingletonFactory *d) { d->~SingletonFactory(); free(d); }
};
```

And in the creation function:

```
SingletonFactory* volatile tmp = (SingletonFactory*) malloc(sizeof(SingletonFactory));
new (tmp) SingletonFactory; // placement new
instance = decltype(instance)(tmp, &deleter);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the answer that I was looking for. I know that there are several ways to achieve singleton behavior (e.g. http://silviuardelean.ro/2012/06/05/few-singleton-approaches/) and the difference between some of them is just the taste. I was looking for a way to improve my own implementation. Guts of getInstance() can easily be switched to something else and I probably do it some time soon (since I switched to C++11), but I wanted to improve my design as a whole.

Comment: @maddening I didn't put it into the answer (because I didn't have time to read the link in your question), but please pay close attention to the comments others have made to your question. A lot of the design decisions in your code (placement `new`, `volatile`) are questionable at best.

Comment: I am well aware of that. I am currently at the process of finding out how to improve code in my project. It's actually more of a self learning project where I can experiment with things to understand C++ better. I will certainly use some of those advises, though - as for now - singletons will stay.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, you can guarantee thread-safe lazy initialisation and destruction at the end of the program using a local static:

```
SingletonAndFactory& SingletonAndFactory::getInstance() {
    static SingletonAndFactory instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Beware that this can still cause lifetime issues, as it may be destroyed before other static objects. If they try to access it from their destructors, then you'll be in trouble.

Before that, it was impossible (although the above was guaranteed by many compilers). As described in the document you link to, `volatile` has nothing to do with thread synchronisation, so your code has a data race and undefined behaviour. Options are:

- Take the (potentially large) performance hit of locking to check the pointer
- Use whatever non-portable atomic intrinsics your compiler provides to test the pointer
- Forget about thread-safe initialisation, and make sure it's initialised before you start your threads
- Don't use singletons

I favour the last option, since it solves all the other problems introduced by the Singleton anti-pattern.